# Reusable blocks in SSIS Package / data as input-output parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working on a package which will use 2 data sources : one is SQL Server, and the other is Cobol.

The goal is to test a parameter at the beginning to chose the good sequence to use.
Once the data is loaded, the rest of the package will be the same for both : for each line, create an output file as json and put it on a server.
What i want to do is to make separated flow for both sources, and a third flow that will work with an unified source (to avoid copy/paste output tasks in the two sequences). But, i don't know if it is possible/how to tell to my dataflow to output its data to the controlflow as an entry parameter to my foreach box :

[image]

Does the dataflow must output its data to a flat file to be reused later ?

I did not see any option to tell my dataflow to output its formatted data to the main flowcontrol, and i don't want to create a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Own answer after many searches :

you need to use a "recordset destination" component, that will be stored in memory as a variable object.
Then,you can use it as a datasource in a foreach task (or anywhere) :

[image: Component to use]

[image: For each configuration example]